# Erosion algorithm javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

With inspiration from https://mewo2.com/notes/terrain/, I try to make my own erosion algorithm.

I tried reading the original paper he linked to, but I have to admit, that I understand nothing and absolute nothing, and there ain't much material on the internet about this specific algorithm.

Then I tried to code his description of the algorithm:

> To calculate this, we start with an infinitely high surface everywhere except on the edge, where we use the original heights. Then, on each iteration, we find points which have a neighbour which is lower than them and set their height to their original height, or the height of their lowest neighbour (plus a small amount), whichever is higher. We halt when we can go a full iteration without changing any point.

I read it like this:

1. Set all seeds to infinity height except seeds at edge, which should be
   the original height
2. Find seed with neighbours who all have lower heights
   then the seed.
3. Set the seeds height to its original height or to the neighbour (+ 0.001) with the lowest height if that is higher than the original height of the seed.
4. Do step two and three until there is no seeds witch gets new height values

My example code looks like this:

```
//1)
for(var i=0; i<seeds.length; i++){
  if(seeds[i].isEdge){
    seeds[i].height = seeds[i].originalHeight;
  } else {
    seeds[i].height = Infinity;
  };
};

//2+3+4
while(true){
  var heightChanged = false;
  for(var i=0; i<seeds.length; i++){
    if(seeds[i].hasLowerNeighbor){
      if(seeds[i].originalHeight>seeds[i].lowestNeighborHeight + 0.001){
        if(seeds[i].height != seeds[i].originalHeight;){
          seeds[i].height = seeds[i].originalHeight;
          heightChanged = true;
        };
      } else {
        if(seeds[i].height != seeds[i].lowestNeighborHeight + 0.001){
          seeds[i].height = seeds[i].lowestNeighborHeight + 0.001;
          heightChanged = true;
        };
      };
    };
  };
  if(!heightChanged){
    break;
  };
};
```

To be honest I don't see how this code should give me any erosion effect, and when I run it just gave me a shadow image of my original seeds heights. Can someone help me to understand the description or/and the original paper, and tell me where I go wrong?

Comment: This is not "pseudo-code" but rather the actual JavaScript you are testing, right? Pseudo-code would be a more general outline.

Comment: @usr2564301 I would imagine `seeds[i].hasLowerNeighbor` is the "pseudo" part.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: well, it's not defined anywhere so it may be... I am trying to decide whether or not it is worth the trouble to copy this onto my system and do a test run. OP states it produces *something*, but this is quite far from a [mcve].

Comment: Lets call it a pseudo JavaScript code then. And no it aint my real code, its a code I wrote to make an example of how I translate his description.
My problem aint this actual code, but to understand the description or/and the original paper from the link.

Comment: Great people can tell me that I used a word wrong, but nobody can help me with the coding part.